# Looking for heroic deeds that don't involve stopping criminal activity

Tags: super-powers

I'm looking for types of heroic deeds that a stereotype superhero or main character in a fiction story does, but with the restriction that it cannot involve (stopping) criminal activity or be too "simple".

Good examples I already have:

- Put out a fire (caused by accident, not by an arsonist)
- Liberate someone from a collapsed cave
- "Catch" a crashing plane and safely land it
- Save a capsized crew
- catch an escaped zoo animal

Examples that don't qualify because of criminal activity:

- Catching a thief and returning the stolen goods
- Preventing a a villian's bomb from derailing a train (killing its passengers)
- Thwart an armed robbery

Examples that don't qualify because they are mundane (in a fictional world - in real life these are awesome):

- Saving a kitty from a tree
- Helping grandma cross the street
- Reading to the blind school children in the public library

It's quite easy to come with scneario's where a villian or crilminal is involved in setting up an evil plot, and the superhero stopping them, but it's harder to think of something spectacular when it's "just an accident".

Comment: Not really what you're looking for, but close enough to be worth mentioning: [link](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2305#comic)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Raw idea generation is a poor fit for this site.  The SE model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  As written, this Q is [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437), meaning you can't judge a best answer (all answers are equally valid).  You can learn more in our [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Stopping a runaway train due to break failure is a good example.  Diverting a flood.

Answer (score 1):

A few:

- Curing diseases and disabilities that otherwise can't be cured
- Stopping hurricanes, tornados, tsunamis etc. from doing damage
- Exploring space and the deep oceans
- Creating/finding valuable resources

Answer (score 0):

**Heal the sick**

If you have a Healing-Hands hero that's about as good as you can possibly get in my book, no criminal activities involved.

I'd even wager that it's 'more good' by most moral frameworks than what the vast majority of superheroes do with their powers. Especially the '*punch crims and lock them up in cardboard prisons*' type, which in the grand scheme of things does little other than escalate the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a list for you:

1. kill an animal that is terrorizing some poor villagers
2. kill another monster that it terrorizing some poor villagers. The monster to be more mosnteric than the previous one could grow two limbs in the place of one they have lost
3. catch a very fast animal, animal faster than arrow.
4. Catch a very large and dangerous animal alive.
5. Clean very dirty place to shine. Like New York, or some city in India.
6. Bring all the Greek statues from UK to Greece
7. Get something to eat from a place that no one actually know if it's exist for real. For example, how does fish that live at the bottom of Marian Trench taste like?
8. Take royal Corgies for a walk.

Answer (score 0):

- assisting the relive afford when some kind of disaster has occurred
- assisting sience (for example a Deadpool like healer offering himself for early human trials to produce medicine)
- beeing an everyday hero (you could call many people, who are going beyond and above their duties in normal jobs heroic)
- raise money for social, scientific or educational projects (a superheros endorsement could help many projects)
- start a cult of personality arround himself (doesn't sound heroic, but the cultists will consider him to be very heroic; look up what Kim Jon Un is doing)

The following suggestions are very dependent on political views. A "good" act does very much depend on the perspective.

- fight ideologie X
- assist a nations (just) war effort
- espionage
- support a "good" politician/party
- kill people who belive in X

The issue with the question is that it notions like "good", "moral" and "heroic" are subjects up for philosophical debate. A suicide bomber would not be considered a hero in  the west, yet his fellow believers in his sect would consider his actions to be very heroic. So asking for a "heroic" deed is a bit of a philosophical rabbit hole.